# Regex (Java) to remove all characters up to but not including (a number or a letter a-f followed by a number)

Tags: java, regex

I need help constructing the regular expression to *remove all characters up to but not including (a number or a letter a-f followed by a number)* in Java:

Here's what I came up with (doesn't work):
`string.replaceFirst(".+?(\\d|[a-f]\\d)","");`

That line of code replaces the entire string with an empty string.
`.+?` is every character up to `\\d` a digit OR `[a-f]\\d` any of the letters a-f followed by a digit.

This doesn't work, however, can I have some help?

Thanks

EDIT: changed `replace` with `replaceFirst`

Comment: `replace` doesn't work on regexes, it works with literals.  Do you want `replaceFirst`?

Comment: Why put so much effort into something that can be done easier, more clearly, faster and better in every way in code.  The ONE advantage that REs might have in this case is coding speed, but if you have to come here you've already blown that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = s.replaceFirst(".*?(?=[a-f]?\\d)", "");
```

Using `.*?` instead of `.+?` insures that the first character gets checked by the lookahead, solving the problem @johusman mentioned.  And while your `(\\d|[a-f]\\d)` isn't causing a problem, `[a-f]?\\d` is both more efficient and more readable.

Answer (score 2):

First off, `replace()` acts on literals, not regexes.  You should use `replaceFirst` or `replaceAll` depending on what you want.  Your regex problem is that you're including the suffix as part of the string to replace.  You can give this a try:

```
input.replaceFirst(".+?(\\d|[a-f]\\d)","$1")
```

Here I just include the suffix in the replacement string as well.  The more correct approach is to make that a zero-width assertion so that it doesn't get included in the region to replace.  You can use a positive lookahead:

```
input.replaceFirst(".+?(?=(\\d|[a-f]\\d))", "")
```

Comment: +1 for the `$1` and replaceFirst; the hex-digit matcher should be just `[0-9a-f]`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest something along the lines of

```
string.replaceFirst(".*?(?=(\\d|[a-f]\\d))", "");
```

Comment: Doesn't work though I can't think why.  It's removing the digit at the end that he wants to keep.  A non-capturing group was my first thought too.

Comment: Oh I know why...I was confused, thinking a non-capturing group is a zero-width assertion.  It isn't, so the group is still consumed and therefore replaced.  You want a positive lookahead as I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers given here have the problem that if the string starts with a-f followed by a number, or just a number, they will actually match and replace the first character. Not sure if that's a relevant scenario. This more convoluted pattern should work though:

```
"([^a-f\\d]|([a-f](?!\\d)))+"
```

(that is, everything that's not a digit or a-f, or a-f not followed by a digit).